# cvlib causing IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable

Tags: python, object-detection

I am trying to follow a simple object detection tutorial using cvlib, but i am consistently running into an IndexError and cannot find anyone else struggling with this issue. Below is the full code i basically copy and pasted from tutorials and the output. Any help is appreciated!

**Code:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cvlib as cv
from cvlib.object_detection import draw_bbox, detect_common_objects
from numpy.lib.polynomial import poly

input = cv2.imread('cars1.jpg')

image = cv2.cvtColor(input,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

plt.axis('off')

box, label, count = cv.detect_common_objects(image)

output = draw_bbox(image, box, label, count)

plt.imshow(output)

plt.show()
```

**Output**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "/Users/zechariahtay/Desktop/ttt.py", 
line 19, in <module>
    box, label, count = cv.detect_common_objects(image)   
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cvlib/object_detection.py",
line 135, in detect_common_objects
    outs = net.forward(get_output_layers(net))   
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cvlib/object_detection.py",
line 29, in get_output_layers
    output_layers = [layer_names[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]   
File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cvlib/object_detection.py",
line 29, in <listcomp>
    output_layers = [layer_names[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()] 
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable
```

Comment: what tutorial? Always add URL in question (not in comment).

Comment: maybe you shouldn't convert to `RGB` if you use CV functions - they all may need `BGR`. You need to convert to `RGB` when you want to display it with `plt`

Comment: OR maybe you should use older Python 3.8 because some modules may not be ready to work with Python 3.9

Comment: code works for me on Python 3.8, Linux Mint 20. I can't test it on 3.9 because I would have to compile `tensorflow` because I have old CPU and standard `tensorflow` can't work.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using OpenCV > 4.5.3 it may be related to this [bug](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/20923) introduced in v4.5.4. I had the same error and it was fixed when I downgraded (`pip3 install opencv-python==4.5.3.56`).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to downgrade your OpenCV version. The later versions return a 1D array containing the indices of each layer. Just avoid indexing (`[0]`) as shown in the following:

`output_layers = [layer_names[i - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]`